# When will GRUB create a new configuration? When I'll change my buster entries to bullseye in sources.list and run apt-get upgrade for Debian 10 to 11?

Tags: debian, grub, upgrade

I'm scared about upgrading my *Debian 10* to *11*, and I'm wondering:

When I will have edited my `sources.list` file, changing the `buster` occurrences to `bullseye` ones,
did an `apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade`,

may I expect that *GRUB* will have "by itself" understood the situation, and created an additional entry into my GRUB boot menu, so that if a boot on *Debian 11* fails, I can immediately reboot on *Debian 10* ?

Or does this requires from me to do another step, first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GRUB setup used in Debian doesn’t care about the version of Debian you’re running, it only cares about the versions of GRUB and the kernel. When you upgrade from Debian 10 to Debian 11, GRUB and the kernel will be upgraded too, and the GRUB menu will be updated to use the new kernel.

Upgrading from Debian 10 to Debian 11 is an in-place upgrade; you won’t have a Debian 10 setup to revert to, so there won’t be a GRUB entry to reboot on Debian 10.

Comment: The old packages and configuration aren't kept at all, and not selectable anymore?

Comment: That’s right, that’s what upgrading does. If you want to keep your old setup you’d have to perform a new installation of Debian 11 alongside it. If you’re worried about upgrading from Debian 10 to Debian 11, there’s nothing forcing you to, Debian 10 is still supported.

Comment: The previous *kernel* should be automatically preserved though, so you’d be able to boot that if necessary (but still running Debian 11).